# Ctags error "Is a directory"

Tags: c++, ctags

I was trying to tag a C++ project with `ctags` with the options as listed in this answer [C++ source tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932396/c-source-tagging).  I am in a project tree that contains multiple folders and those folders contain source files.  I have tried the following to tag the entire source tree

```
ctags --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language-force=C++ -R .
find . -type f \( -iname "*.cpp" -o -iname "*.hpp" \) | xargs ctags --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language-force=C++
ctags -R . 
ctags -R *
```

and all of the above give the same error

```
ctags: Failure on attempt to read file : Is a directory
```

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out this was a case insensitive filesystem problem.  The MacOSX I am on has case insensitive files and as a result a folder named `Tags` was affecting the ctags program.  Removing the `Tags` folder or causing ctags to output to another file with the `-f` flag fixed the issue.

Comment: Same goes on CentOS Linux

Comment: I actually ran into this error when I used the default Ubuntu Linux ctags. Was able to resolve by installing ctags via `sudo apt-get install ctags`