# How do I jump to class-qualified tags in VIM?

Tags: vim, tags, ctags

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1932526/622049), we're given the valuable tip to include`--extra=+q` when we're working with C++ code. What this answer doesn't address is [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932396/c-source-tagging/#comment59329083_1932396) bewailing how difficult is to *use* the class-qualified tags.

You can search for a qualified tag with `:tag /pattern` but this solution is cumbersome. Is there any way to get the correct tag with the default `CTRL-]`? Solutions that are "just OK" are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the workaround mentioned in that comment satisfies you, you should use `:tjump /pattern` instead of `:tag /pattern`. It behaves like `:tag /pattern` when there's only one match and like `:tselect /pattern` when there are several matches.

The normal mode equivalent of `:tjump` is `g<C-]>` but it behaves like `:tjump pattern`, not like `:tjump /pattern` and there's no way to make it work like that except remapping it:

```
nnoremap g<C-]> :tjump /<C-r><C-a><CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a visual selection and include the class qualifier, the normal tag jump commands will include the whole visual selection in the lookup.

I use `C-V` to start a visual selection, move to the end of the name, and then use `C-]`, or `g` then `]` as usual

Also, `vi -t some_class::some_method` works on the command line

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
:set iskeyword+=:
```

then Vim sees `myclass::mymethod` as one word. You can then do `<C-]>` anywhere on it to jump to the class-qualified tag.